# Generate aggregate report in JMeter from command line

Tags: jmeter

We know below command generate .jtl file.

jmeter -n –t test.jmx -l testresults.jtl

Is there any way to generate aggregate report in csv format as output of above command line ?

Answer (score 2):

It is but you will need to install some [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/):

- [Synthesis Report](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SynthesisReport/)
- [JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/)

you can install the plugins using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

Once done you will be able to generate the textual representation of the Aggregate Report listener like:

```
JMeterPluginsCMD --generate-csv AggregateReport.csv --input-jtl testresults.jtl --plugin-type AggregateReport
```

More information: [How to Use the JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeterpluginscmd-command-line)

Comment: Hi Dmitri,  Thanks for your valuable inputs.  I am getting below error. C:\apache-jmeter-5.4.1\apache-jmeter-5.4.1\lib\ext>JMeterPluginsCMD.bat --generate-csv "C:\AggregateReport.csv" --input-jtl "C:\ReportPOC\Report\result.jtl" --plugin-type AggregateReport
ERROR: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.jmeter.save.CSVSaveService.saveCSVStats(Ljava/util/List;Ljava/io/FileWriter;[Ljava/lang/String;)

Comment: looks like version compatibility issue ?